# How to enter Dot in the android keyboard?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I wanted to type rd@gmail.com in the email field.

I am using the command below.

```
# Press Dot on the key board

device.press('KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT', 'DOWN_AND_UP','')
```

This command is not recognized. It is coming that key is not found. Please let me know how to enter this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

'KEYCODE_PERIOD'